# Big white box obscures the body of meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, font-size, browsers

When I visit meta.stackoverflow.com, there is a big white box which obscures the "Top Questions" section. Please see the attached screenshot.

I am running Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows XPSP3. I have occasionally seen this using Firefox 3 or 4, on other computers (Mac, Gnome, Windows XP) but I never took a screenshot from those systems.

[image: Big White Box]

**20110518 Update:**

I can workaround this problem by using full page zoom (Menu option "View: Zoom: Zoom In", otherwise known as `Ctrl++`). If I hit `Ctrl++` once, the big white box goes away. However, it will reappear if I hit `Ctrl++` a few more times.

If I hit `Ctrl+-` a few times, the problem reappears.

Comment: On Gaming, we had a similar report here: [Unexplained white space devours half of front page! Citizens now in terror!](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/unexplained-white-space-devours-half-of-front-page-citizens-now-in-terror). It was on Firefox as well.

Comment: That's not exactly the only thing wrong with that screenshot; something is very broken

Comment: Clearly, the OP hit `Ctrl` + `+`, increasing `pageFontSize` from 12 to 14 and `pageWhiteBoxSize` from 0 to 1000. Seriously though, the screenshot at the Gaming report doesn't have the same text size issues as this.

Comment: @Popular : Are you saying that this behavior happened because I increased the font size in my browser?

Comment: the first part of my comment was a joke, where I was suggesting exactly that. The second part was to point out that this _may_ be a different bug, or the same bug plus a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this.

Be aware of the two kinds of browser zoom

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html

We only support +1 and -1 for font zooming, but full page zoom of course scales pretty much infinitely.

Comment: I have this issue in the standard browser on my Blackberry Bold.  (The mobile version is gorgeous, but I use the full-site when I want to flag something.)

Answer (score 0):

Your default font size is increased in your browser's settings.  You can change it in 'under-the-hood' in Chrome, or in the font settings in FireFox.  I had the same issue and posted the same question here on meta, and Yi Jiang gave me the answer in a comment.