# Horizontal-scroll frame and buttons misplaced on MSO

Tags: bug, questions, design, visibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Big white box obscures the body of meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91675/big-white-box-obscures-the-body-of-meta-stackoverflow-com)

### Image One:

[image]

---

### Image Two:

[image]

I circled the areas where I see issues.  The content is covered.  Two images are necessary to show what's happening in its entirety.

Description: Questions are covered.

Expected: See questions from the top of the page.

Actual result: I need to scroll to the bottom of the page to get a horizontal scroll bar so that I can see questions.

I'll try to adjust my browser's style sheet, but I haven't done it before.  If there's any update, I'll let you know.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Also, what resolution and which device (or operating system) are you using?

Comment: Your default font size appears to be too big

Comment: Chrome, latest.  1024x768.

Comment: Can't repro this in Chrome latest, no matter what size I make my fonts. They can be absolutely ginormous without triggering the "Giant White Box" preference.

Comment: @cody, Yi Jiang has the correct answer, but he has not posted it as an answer.

Comment: The problem is fixed when you change the font size? Even if I jack the font size way up, I get a site that looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EpGU6.png). Not exactly beautiful, but completely usable. At least I can still *see* everything. The issue has been reported before (see link provided by Popular Demand) but no one on the dev team seems to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: @cody, there's more than one way to increase font size.  Browse: chrome://settings/advanced.  Go to the font size drop-down menu and select "very large".

Comment: That's exactly what I did... Maybe it's an OS issue. I can't tell from the scrollbars if that's an old version of Windows or XWindows.

Comment: Yes.  I confirmed it fixes it to turn it to medium.

Comment: @cody os: XP.  Maybe so.  I saw an answer on Stack Overflow that suggested a fix for this issue within CSS.  Create a hidden DIV and put a letter inside of it.  Base the stylesheet on the size of the DIV.