# Tag wiki excerpts getting displayed incorrectly on SO with FF 10

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki-excerpt, browsers

Tag wiki excerpts have been getting displayed improperly in Firefox 10.0.2 for the past three hours or so. They're being shown as tall boxes (`div`s) on the left side of the screen instead of short boxes using the full width of the column. It's wasting a lot of space in the middle of the screen. Here's a screenshot:

[image: tag wiki excerpt stuck to left side of page]

This is the correct layout, which I can see in Internet Explorer and another copy of Firefox:

[image: tag wiki excerpt laid out normally]

only from root [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) to the every

Related Tags

[image]

current add_on & plugins

[image]

Comment: @Geoff How is that by-design?

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm not able to reproduce this - I'll retag.

Comment: notice this issue is caused cca 3-4 hours, without restarting FF, updates on demand, last updates for FF ??? week or two back ???

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Same FF version.

Comment: Norepro from me, same FF version. Which addons do you guys have?

Comment: @Xeo: HTTPS everywhere, and Greasemonkey (no scripts installed, though)

Comment: @Xeo see my edit about addons & plugins

Comment: ... Win updates a patches were sometime on last week :-)

Comment: You used *This is the correct layout, which I can see in Internet Explorer*.  **Its super effective!**

Comment: @Won't hehehe this's the superlativ in compare with FF :-)

Comment: Now [reported in Chromium](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125421/page-design-broken-on-stackoverflow) as well... maybe a Verdana/Arial issue?

Comment: @Popular Demand I'll check that and change Font family in the FF settings (up-to 2-3 hours)

Comment: @Popular Demand please see my answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Popular Demand you are right, this about Font used by WebServices, this feature is possible to disabling in the `Mozilla Firefox`, notice preview of majorities from web sites is more than terrible ..., I'd have to live with buggy preview :-)

by default is checked option [Allow pages to choose their own fonts](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Options%20window%20-%20Content%20panel#w_fonts-dialog) with output to the screen

image

[image]

```
Disabling this option will force all sites to use your default fonts instead.
```

then output to the screen is (`Font Times New Roman`)

image

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your text zoom level may be off - reset the zoom level by:

[image: reset zoom]

If you want to zoom use the browser zoom which zooms the entire page, not just the fonts (CTRL-+)

Comment: thanks no changes, maybe something are cached, I'd have to try log off/on :-)

Comment: I see the same issue with the same version of Firefox, and resetting the zoom does not change the behavior. I also notice that this happens only on some excerpts (e.g. I see the extra space when viewing questions tagged wireshark, but not questions tagged elf).

Comment: [Font zoom by ±1 has historically been considered "supported"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91727/159251) here. Has this changed?

Comment: Is this still an issue?